# Azure front door resource not appearing in azure dns when adding apex domain

Tags: azure-front-door, azure-dns

I suffer a problem when adding the apex for a custom domain for a front door instance in azure dns. Accordingly to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain), it should be possible to select the specific front door resource, but in my case, nothing appears.

Both, the dns-zone as well as the front door instance are contained within the same subscription, as well as the same resource group.

Anyone having same problems?
Many thanks in advice!

[image: No front door instance appearing]

Comment: Same issuer here 5 months after! Can't believe MSFT haven't fixed it yet